# How to disable form's postValidator in symfony 1.4

Tags: forms, symfony1, validation

I have pre, post and "regular" validators.

How can I completely disable postvalidator or check for failure from postvalidator if "regular" validator has already failed?

Comment: got some code so we know what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible using some Symfony setting. The `sfValidatorSchema` checks everything, so all errors are reported to the user. And normally, this is exactly what you want.

So, I don't know what your postvalidator looks like, but if it's custom built, you can probably just check if the value in the `$values` array is empty. If so, just return the values without throwing an error.

Comment: I check field validity in regular validator and conditional validity in postvalidator.
Does NULL in $values definitely tell that value for a field is not valid?

Comment: No, not "definitely", because theoretically other validators could output `NULL` as value. But it's a really good indicator, because if a validation fails, it gets the NULL value. But it all depends on your form. Maybe you could update your question with the form code?

Comment: I'd like to post code but I get "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly." message whatever I do.

Comment: just the `$this->widgetSchema['widget1'] = new sfWidget...` and `$this->validatorSchema['widget1'] = new sfValidator...` line for the affected widgets, and the  `$this->setPostValidator(...)` line will suffice.

Comment: though check for NULL is ugly it works. thanks Grad for confirming absence of other means